# Why does what should be an email address appear as Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactField?

Tags: c#, windows-8, contacts, windows-store-apps

I've got this code:

```
private async void ButtonSelectContact_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker
    {
        CommitButtonText = "Invite"
    };
    var contact = await contactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync();
    if (contact != null)
    {
        textBoxPerson.Text = contact.Name;
        textBoxEmail.Text = contact.Emails[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

..which works well, except that after selecting a contact, textBoxEmail.Text contains "Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactField" (it should be something like "rupertTpupkin@kingOfComedy.com").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `contacts.Emails` is a list of `ContactField` objects.  Use `contact.Emails[0].Value` to get the email address you want. You can use `.Type` to retrieve the type of the email address.

Official MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactfield

Answer (score 1):

Because they didn't override the ToString() method when implementing the class, so it is calling the Object's ToString() method, which returns the class name.  You can call `contact.Emails[0].Value` to get the value.